# Which electrical characteristics of stator and rotor windings influence the mechanical power of a single phase induction motor?

Tags: induction-motor

I wish to find the values of resistance, inductance and mutual inductance of stator and rotor windings of a single phase, two poles, capacitor-start, capacitor-run induction motor with 1/2 Hp mechanical output power. The mains voltage is 230 V with frequency 50 Hz. The slip is 2.78%. I have successfully done this using genetic algorithms achieving high efficiency and balanced operation of the two stator windings at operation at nominal rpm. Nethertheless I would like to know the most salient features that determine the output power from a physical-electrical engineering point of view.

Comment: Start with the motor data sheet...

Comment: The thing is I am trying to design a 1/2 Hp motor from scratch as I can't find any datasheet for a 1/2 Hp motor. My textbooks don't contain any relevant information either. They have some examples or exercises for other power or mains voltage specifications. The information is very dense and I would just like to have a mere physical reasoning for the selection of the appropriate values if possible

Comment: This looks like it is too broad ie it is not one single question - there are books about the design parameters...

Comment: I have a book that explains in detail how to design motors. It starts with DC machines and proceeds through synchronous, induction wound-rotor and squirrel-cage motors to single-phase motors. In each section there are parts that are described in terms of the differences between that section and previous sections. Power is torque multiplied by speed. Torque is proportional to the length X diameter of the air gap. The ampere-turns must be determined to produce as much flux as the iron can support. The resistance and stray reactance influence  the required voltage. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: @Charles Cowie The comment regarding the torque and flux was the kind of explanation I needed. Is it possible to name the book you mentioned??

Comment: John H. Kuhlmann "Design of Electrical Apparatus" 2nd Ed, John Wiley & Sons, 1940